# Websocket in PHP-generated Javascript won't connect?

Tags: php, websocket

I have a PHP site that generates some HTML and Javascript. The Javascript initializes a `Websocket` and sends a message to the server after `onopen` fires. It works locally, but over the internet the connection is never established.

I'm trying to pin down the error. I have connected via websocket to my server across the internet from a plain html site with Javascript before. Is there any security mechanism against websockets in PHP sites or something? Here's the code briefly, can't see why it shouldn't work (especially since it works locally):

```
<?php
    echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
              <head>
                  <script src=\"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js\"></script>
                  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src=\"js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js\"><\/script>');</script>
              </head>
              <body>
                  <script>
                      var socket;
                      var host = \"ws://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:1237/websocket\";  

                       $(document).ready(function()
                       {            
                           connect();  
                       });  

                       function connect()
                       {  
                            socket = new WebSocket(host); 
                            socket.onopen = function()
                            {
                                  // never fires
                            };  
                        }
                   </script>
              </body>
          </html>";
?>
```

Comment: did you check the view source of the php page to see if this is echoed properly?

Comment: <head>...</head> can I assume that you have linked the jquery js file inside your head tag>

Comment: @SajithNair Yes it is echoed properly, sadly. And I do have a jquery js linked.

Comment: Okay I'm pretty certain now that the solution is very simple, namely a port not being open. Thanks for your help, will report back in a bit to confirm my suspicion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for wasting your time. I hadn't opened a port.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jQuery js file is NOT linked in your `<head>` tag.

Following code will not work without jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{            
    connect();  
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I shouldn't have left that out. I do have it linked. ready() fires, I have an alert() in there that gets called.